# videojs, trigger different youtube urls, manually

Tags: youtube, video.js

I'm interested in manually (click a button) triggering the playing of different youtube urls using the same html video tag (if possible) with videojs.

I saw this code which gives me hope that this is feasible: http://jsfiddle.net/mister_ben/g7mrs/

html code:

```
<video id="myPlayer" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="320" height="180" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D36JUfE1oYk" }'></video>
<p><a href="#" onClick="loadVideo()">Another video</a></p>
```

js code:

```
function loadVideo(event) {
    videojs("myPlayer").src({ type: "video/youtube", src: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"});
    event.preventDefault();                  
}
```

But this is old code (videojs version 4.1 and an older version of the videojs- youtube plugin), and upgrading to the current versions just doesn't do the trick.

I'm using the youtube plugin (https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube) for videojs.

Is that even possible now with the new apis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the author and he provided an example here: 
https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/issues/339#issuecomment-164592838

Here is an example of it working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.4/video-js.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<video
    id="vid1"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls
    width="640" height="264"
    data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ"}] }'
    >
</video>


<button id="change">change video</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.4/video.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eXon/videojs-youtube/637a2916c2c4fd2b5fc55dafa3df923a92fec6d0/src/Youtube.js"></script>
<script>

    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // An example of playing with the Video.js javascript API
            // Will start the video and then switch the source 3 seconds latter
            // You can look at the doc there: http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/api.html
            videojs('vid1').ready(function () {
                var myPlayer = this;
                myPlayer.src({type: 'video/youtube', src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6Sxv-sUYtM'});

                $("#change").on('click', function () {
                    myPlayer.src({type: 'video/youtube', src: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09R8_2nJtjg'});
                });
            });

        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**To playing different youtube urls in ionic using Videojs player.**

Here is an example of it working:

```
page.html

    <video id='video' width="100%" controls preload="auto" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered vjs-16-9"></video>


page.ts

this.videoJSplayer = videojs(document.getElementById('video'), {
  controls: true,
  autoplay: true,
  techOrder: ["youtube"],
  height: "200"
 });

 this.videoJSplayer.src({type:'video/youtube',src:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xwo-H5krlj0"})
```